# android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: server_preferences (code 1)

Tags: android, sqlite

I am uploading my app on playstore and this error comes from the Pre launch report. Below is the full stack trace :

FATAL EXCEPTION: Background tasks
android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: server_preferences (code 1): , while compiling: SELECT * FROM server_preferences WHERE (name = ?)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativePrepareStatement(Native Method)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.acquirePreparedStatement(SQLiteConnection.java:1118)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.prepare(SQLiteConnection.java:691)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.prepare(SQLiteSession.java:588)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.(SQLiteProgram.java:58)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.(SQLiteQuery.java:37)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.query(SQLiteDirectCursorDriver.java:44)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.rawQueryWithFactory(SQLiteDatabase.java:1436)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:400)
at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQueryBuilder.query(SQLiteQueryBuilder.java:294)
at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine.getServerPrefsCursor(MailEngine.java:1462)
at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine.getCursorForReplyFromDefaultAddress(MailEngine.java:1466)
at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine.notifyInitializationComplete(MailEngine.java:1371)
at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine.access$1900(MailEngine.java:135)
at com.google.android.gm.provider.MailEngine$5.run(MailEngine.java:1291)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:730)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:176)
at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)

I dont have a table named server_preference in the app.
Please let me know what can be done for this?

Comment: That's from a google component. You can try rerunning the prelaunch tests to see if it was just some test flakiness and not systematic.

Comment: We tried that but still got the same report.

Comment: did you solve this problem, I'm experiencing this problem from google play console too

Comment: @quickbrown no. I just uploaded the app again and the error didnt show up again